# Using Passport.js with Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, express, passport.js

This is my passport local config. I'm wrapping it inside a function so I can use it some where else:

```
export const LocalPassport = (passport: any, strategy: any) => {
  passport.use(
    new strategy(
      {
        usernameField: 'email',
        passwordField: 'password',
        passReqToCallback: true,
        session: false,
      },
      async (req: Request, email: string, password: string, done: any) => {
        try {
          const user = await AuthService.findUserByEmail(email)

          if (!user) {
            return done(null, false)
          }

          const passCheck = bcrypt.compare(password, user.password)
          if (!passCheck) {
            return done(null, false)
          }

          return done(null, user)
        } catch (error) {
          console.log(error)
        }
      }
    )
  )
}
```

And I use it in my login router:

```
import express from 'express'
import passport from 'passport'
import Strategy from 'passport-local'
import bodyParser from 'body-parser'

import { createUser } from '../controllers/auth'
import FormValidate from '../middlewares/FormValidate'
import { LocalPassport } from '../config/passport'

import User from '../models/User'

LocalPassport(passport, Strategy.Strategy)

const router = express.Router()
router.use(passport.initialize())
router.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
router.use(bodyParser.json())

//**path for api/v1/auth */
router.post('/register', FormValidate.register, createUser)
router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local'), async (req, res) => {
  try {
    res.send('logged in')
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
})

export default router
```

When I test this route from postman, I received a long list of errors, but it starts with: **RangeError [ERR_HTTP_INVALID_STATUS_CODE]: Invalid status code: undefined** I tried to `console.log` and I can see bcrypt compares return `true`, I believe the error happens after `done` is invoked

What am I doing wrong here ?? And how should I replace the `any` types in passport config file. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured the error was because I did not set up session for passport, and after authentication it tried to set up a session, hence the error. I fixed this by:

```
router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local', {session: false}), async (req, res) => {
  try {
    res.send('logged in')
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
})
```